# Swift memory address of outside instance of inout parameter same as copied instance

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This is my playground code.

```
import Foundation

func printAddress<T>(anyObj: T,message: String = "") {
  var copy = anyObj
  withUnsafePointer(to: &copy) {
    print("\(message) value \(copy) has memory address of: \($0)")
  }
}


class Account {
  var balance: Int = 0
  init(balance: Int) {
    self.balance = balance
  }
}

func deposit(amount: Int, into account: inout Account) {
  account.balance += amount

  printAddress(anyObj: account, message: "After deposit") //0x00007fff569ba188
  printAddress(anyObj: acct,message: "Address of acct within the deposit free function") //0x00007fff59eb6188
  //What makes both memory addresses are same inside the fucntion?
}

func verify(account: Account) -> Bool{
  printAddress(anyObj: acct,message: "Address of acct within the verify function") //0x00007fff5a39a188
  //Again surprisingly same as address used in deposit function copied account var. Optimization?
  return account.balance > 0
}

var acct = Account(balance: 10)
printAddress(anyObj: acct,message:"Before deposit 20") // Print 0x00007fff518751f8

deposit(amount: 20, into: &acct)
verify(account: acct)

printAddress(anyObj: acct,message:"After and deposit and verify completed") //// Print 0x00007fff518751f8
```

I have 2 observations that are not clear to me.

1. Why it prints the same memory address for `account`(Copied instance) and `acct`(The original acct)
2. When I print the memory address inside verify method call. Why it again same as the address used in previous method call. Is it something due to compiler optimisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that you're always printing the address of the `copy` variable inside the `printAddress()` function.  You're *not* printing the address of the argument you passed in, even though that is what you intended.

The address of the `copy` variable is always some constant fixed offset past the stack pointer that is current when `printAddress()` is entered, but the stack pointer changes depending on how deeply nested your code is when `printAddress()` is called.

To see yet another value, make a function `foo()` that calls `printAddress()`, and call `foo()` from `verify()`.

Again, it's always the memory address of the `copy` variable you see at the point in time that `print()` is called.

If you want to print the memory address of the thing passed to `printAddress()`, you'll need to get rid of the temporary:

```
func printAddress<T>(anyObj: inout T, message: String = "") {
    withUnsafePointer(to: &anyObj) {
        print("\(message) value \(anyObj) has memory address of: \($0)")
    }
}
```

Now call:

`printAddress(anyObj: &acct, message: "message")`

From anywhere and you'll see the same value.

Comment: That was a silly mistake I made. Great explanation on stack pointer. This answer corrected the mistake. I have a new question though. After correcting the `printAddress` function. I changed `Account` to a `struct`. Now according to the apple definition of `inout` still values get copied and written back when function returns. So within the `deposit` function if I print address of `account` function parameter it should be a different value. But it is not?

Comment: From Documentation >> As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body. The optimized behavior is known as call by reference; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in copy-out model while removing the overhead of copying. Write your code using the model given by copy-in copy-out, without depending on the call-by-reference optimization, so that it behaves correctly with or without the optimization.

Comment: +1 as you've answered your own question. Optimizations like this are one of the reasons I find value types in Swift to be really well-designed, but you do have to be aware of the implications, particularly if you're using the `inout` parameter(s) in a closure or in multithreaded code as the rest of the docs point out. Honestly though I don't see either of these use cases coming up all that often.